# djl game manager installation problems

Tags: games, software-installation

I'm trying to get djl (game manager) from: http://en.djl-linux.org/?q=node/19

After getting the pakage, I followed the instructions for installation from: http://www.unixmen.com/install-more-then-100-games-in-one-command/

I used the command `tar -zxvf  djl-1.2.14.tar.gz`. And the output came out as:

```
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$ tar -zxvf  djl-1.2.14.tar.gz
tar (child): djl-1.2.20.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Then i used this command:

```
tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/djl-1.2.20.tar.gz
```

But i get this:

```
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$ tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/djl-1.2.20.tar.gz
djl/
djl/djl.sh
djl/djl/
djl/djl/Journal.txt
djl/djl/.eric4project/
djl/djl/.eric4project/project-apis.db
djl/djl/res/
djl/djl/res/b_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/transp.png
djl/djl/res/quitter.png
djl/djl/res/modules_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/winehq.png
djl/djl/res/configuration.png
djl/djl/res/txt_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/irc_crystal.png
djl/djl/res/importer.png
djl/djl/res/echange_ui_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/redemarre_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/msg_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/ajouter.png
djl/djl/res/maj_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/configure_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/a_propos.png
djl/djl/res/jeux_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/actus.png
djl/djl/res/supprimer_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/arg_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/telech1.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/italy.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/sweden.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/poland.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/espagne.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/france.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/galicia.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/portugal.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/hu.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/de.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/ru.png
djl/djl/res/drapeaux/en.png
djl/djl/res/information.png
djl/djl/res/retirer.png
djl/djl/res/maj.png
djl/djl/res/locale_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/recherche_oxygen.png
djl/djl/res/irc_crystal_mp.png
djl/djl/gdep.py
djl/djl/djl_main.py
djl/djl/irc.py
djl/djl/variables.py
djl/djl/config.py
djl/djl/diff.py
djl/djl/libs/
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/SOAPBuilder.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/WSDLTools.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/c14n.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/test/
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/test/test_wstools.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/test/test_wsdl.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/test/__init__.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/test/test_t1.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/test/test_wstools_net.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/__init__.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLSchema.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLname.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/Utility.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/TimeoutSocket.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/Namespaces.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/logging.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/wstools/UserTuple.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/Server.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/ChangeLog
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/LICENSE
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/Client.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/version.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/__init__.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/fpconst/
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/fpconst/__init__.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/Parser.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/Types.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/SOAP.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/URLopener.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/Utilities.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/NS.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/README
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/WSDL.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/Config.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/GSIServer.py
djl/djl/libs/SOAPpy/Errors.py
djl/djl/libs/feedparser/
djl/djl/libs/feedparser/__init__.py
djl/djl/libs/irclib/
djl/djl/libs/irclib/__init__.py
djl/djl/libs/Fopen.py
djl/djl/libs/test_ws.py
djl/djl/rss.py
djl/djl/djl.py
djl/djl/configuration.py
djl/djl/installe.py
djl/djl/depot.py
djl/djl/image.png
djl/djl/ajout_jeu.py
djl/djl/interface.py
djl/djl/navigateur.py
djl/djl/icone.png
djl/djl/i18n/
djl/djl/i18n/sv_SE/
djl/djl/i18n/sv_SE/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/sv_SE/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/sv_SE/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/ru_RU/
djl/djl/i18n/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/pl_PL/
djl/djl/i18n/pl_PL/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/pl_PL/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/pl_PL/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/de_DE/
djl/djl/i18n/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/pt_PT/
djl/djl/i18n/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/it_IT/
djl/djl/i18n/it_IT/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/it_IT/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/it_IT/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/es_ES/
djl/djl/i18n/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/gl_ES/
djl/djl/i18n/gl_ES/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/gl_ES/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/gl_ES/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/fr_FR/
djl/djl/i18n/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/en_US/
djl/djl/i18n/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n/hu_HU/
djl/djl/i18n/hu_HU/LC_MESSAGES/
djl/djl/i18n/hu_HU/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
djl/djl/i18n/hu_HU/LC_MESSAGES/djl.po
djl/djl/i18n.py
djl/djl/palette_irc.py
djl/djl/import_raccourcis.py
djl/djl/modules.py
djl/djl/Journal_en.txt
djl/webservice-src/
djl/webservice-src/djl.php
djl/webservice-src/djl.sql
djl/webservice-src/COPYING
djl/README
djl/LISEZMOI
djl/COPYING
djl/LIESMICH
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$
```

Is it installed or not? When i search "djl" in dash it doesn't show.

The output of `ls ~/Downloads | grep djl` is :

```
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$ ls ~/Downloads | grep djl
djl-1.2.20.tar.gz
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$
```

But if i use:

```
tar -xvf djl-1.2.20.tar.gz
```

Output is:

```
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$ tar -xvf djl-1.2.20.tar.gz
tar: djl-1.2.20.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$
```

Another error!

So i installed gdebi (an installing application) and downloaded djl.deb from [here](https://launchpad.net/djl)

Right-clicked djl.deb and select "open with gdebi". This is what i get in the terminal of gdebi:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /home/dell/Downloads/djl.deb (--install):
 parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 2 package 'djl':
 error in 'Version' field string '1.2.19_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in version number
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/dell/Downloads/djl.deb
```

Using the `cd` command and the output is:

```
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$ cd /home/downloads
bash: cd: /home/downloads: No such file or directory
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$
```

Did i type something wrong or what?

Seems like i have a problem with the directory's. Please help! Thanks to all the people that help me!

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

`djl.deb` has problems with dependencies:

[image]

I suggest you to use `tar.gz` sources. But your expectations were wrong: `tar -xzf` does not install the archive, it just unpacks it to the current directory. To launch Djl, you have to launch `djl.sh`:

```
cd Downloads
tar -xzf djl-1.2.20.tar.gz
djl/djl.sh
```

[image]

To finish Djl installation, you should move it to `/opt` and make symlink to `djl.sh`:

```
sudo mv djl /opt
sudo ln -s /opt/djl/djl.sh /usr/local/bin/djl
```

After that, you can run Djl just typing `djl` in the Terminal.

If your goal is to make it visible in the Dash, you have to make `.desktop` file for it (hope you know how to do it; if not, simply use one of `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` as basis) and place in `~/.local/share/applications`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Djl
Exec=djl
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/opt/djl
Icon=/opt/djl/icone.png
GenericName[en_US]=Game manager
```

Answer (score 1):

By default downloaded files would be stored inside the `~/Downloads` directory. So run the below command to extract the .gz file to the same directory.

```
tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/djl-1.2.20.tar.gz
```

Then you can access the extracted contents on Downloads directory through nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install the DJL by downloading the .deb file from [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/djl/trunk).

Then go to the downloaded file directory ( ex. /Downloads)

```
cd [FILE DIRECTORY HERE]
```

Then install it by :

```
sudo dpkg -i [.DEB FILE NAME HERE]
```